# 301 redirect remote management

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-301

Is there a good way of remotely managing 301 redirects in IIS?  I have recently taken ownership of a small retail ASP.NET website I've been tasked with providing our SEO provider the ability to change redirects for old products etc without having direct access to the server, or needing us to make the change.

The website is ASP.NET 4.0, running on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.

Comment: Is there/could there be a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could maintain a list of the required redirects via an app.config file - have a module which takes the request and checks the request against the file

if there is a match then you could redirect to a known place. The trouble is that it could be a little slow - instead of a config file you could store the redirects in the database as an alternative

Comment: Would that be an HTTP handler module? I suppose ideally it would read and cache the redirects from the database in Application_Start?

Comment: yeah a http handler - you could load the entire list of redirects into cache at app_start as you said then its a matter of reading from memory. trouble with this is that if one needs to be added then it wont show up until the app domain is reset